# export table data to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal-8

I'm writing PHP code (in drupal) to export data to excel file using ajax i'm not receiving any error but file is not getting download when I click button to export to excel. 
But file getting download when i directly heat the url(from browser)

This is the ajax code

```
jQuery('.export-csv', context).once('export').click(function() {
console.log('test');

var role = 'teacher';

 /*get basepath*/
 var basepath = drupalSettings.path.baseUrl;
jQuery.ajax({
 type : 'GET',
url  : basepath + 'report-export/'+role,
    success : function (data) {
console.log('success');
},
error: function () {
console.log('error');
}
})
})
```

and php function in controller to download excel file

```
 public function exportToExcel($role)
    {
        $filename = "report.xls";       
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        $records = array(
        '0' => array('Name'=> 'user1', 'Status' =>'complete', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'001'),
        '1' => array('Name'=> 'user2', 'Status' =>'inprogress', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'111'),
        '2' => array('Name'=> 'user3', 'Status' =>'hold', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'333'),
        '3' => array('Name'=> 'user4', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'444'),
        '4' => array('Name'=> 'user5', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777'),
        '5' => array('Name'=> 'user6', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777')
        );

$heading = false;
    if(!empty($records))
      foreach($records as $row) {
        if(!$heading) {
          // display field/column names as a first row
          echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
          $heading = true;
        }
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
      }
        exit;
    }
```

though i m not getting error but file not getting downloading. and in ajax console also getting success message. and when i direct hit url as
    `site.com/report-export/`  file gets download

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few header tags to make this work. This works for me, procedural style. Quick, hassle-free.

**form.php**

```
 <a class="btn btn-default" href="download.php">Download Excelsheet</a>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
$file = '../path-to/filename.csv';//csv
$file = '../path-to/filename.xls';//excel

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');//csv
    header("Content-Type: application/xls");//excel
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: above one is for csv, I m expecting excel export

Comment: This will work for any type of file you have. I will edit my answer for xls.